# global constants and include path to my CMS pages

Tags: php, configuration, content-management-system, constants

We have a CMS wich creates  pages (folders with index.php) in file system with unlimited depth.
Users are able  to add, edit and move the page to levels up/down.
I am searching for best server independent approach how to set up the include path to start always from the site root (or use with sub root) to call global usable constants of my config.php.

Would like to avoid use of  .htacces or custom php.ini, since i do not know security settings of any server in advance.
Of course, security matters.

The best available option until now, is to include in each page template top (where wwwmap 
 is web root):

```
  $doc_root="C:\\wwwmap\\subfolder\\";
  ini_set("include_path", get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $doc_root );  
  include_once("sitesetup.php");
```

(where in sitesetup.php, config.php is called and session start)
Your ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` work (instead of $doc_root)?
http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Yes, that's what i tried first (worked perfect on localhost)  but $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] on some live machines, Windows servers, outputs  C:/wwwmap/domain.com/ (including current domain), but i need  C:/wwwmap/ only.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be default behaviour? I'd say that the domain should be part of the document root.

Comment: sorry, i know i confused you a little bit. i need to make sure that in cases, where installation will run as 'alias' settings, the correct path is taken into consideration. In this case, DOCUMENT_ROOT does not really help. C:/wwwmap/ is what i am looking for

Comment: If alias is placed into wwwmap root (same level as master domain), DOCUMENT_ROOT will return www.domain.com/alias_folder, but what i actually need is C:/wwwmap/alias_folder. Hope this clarifies